# In CouchDB 2.0, why is last_seq on changes() different than update_seq on info()?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

In CouchDB 2.0, I noticed that the database's info 'update_seq' property has the same number, but different text, than the changes feed 'last_seq' property. Why is that?

Comment: I really want to understand that too, since `couchdb-lucene` relies on that to index the database correctly. When these values are different, the search times out. There's something related to `pouchdb` live sync, but I don't know exactly what.